# validations in an unwind segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an iOS game that uses a modal view controller to let a user change settings for the game.  If, for example, using a made up example, the user chooses `5` for the number of `cats` on the screen, I only want to let the user have no more than `4 bullets`. If the user chooses `6 cats`, then he/she can have up to `5 bullets`. They can never have more bullets than cats.  I am using UIPicker to set the number of cats and the number of bullets, so the Picker actually allows the user to set 3 cats, and 6 bullets. Therefore, when the modal unwinds, I want to be able to stop the unwind and present a message telling the user that there should be more cats than bullets etc.

Question:

1 I know how to compare the settings selected in the designated unwind method (a simple task), but how do I stop the modal from unwinding so that the user is forced to readjust the settings to comply with game rules.

2 Is there a way in the  modal to only show the number of bullets after the user has selected the number of cats and to therefore limit the number of bullets available based on the number of cats selected?

Update. I'm able to call pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent after selection of the number of cats, but I'm not sure how to use that to limit the number of bullets. The code below doesn't work

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if(component == 0)
    {
        return [ _cats objectAtIndex:row];
        [self pickerView:self didSelectRow:row inComponent:0];
    }
    else
    {
        return [_bullets objectAtIndex:row];
    }

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if (row == 3){
      _bullets = @[@"1",@"2"];       //this part isn't working. not sure how to limit
                                     //number of bullets based on row selected
    }else if (row == 4){
      _bullets = @[@"1", "2", "3"];
    } 
  ....


}
```

Comment: Might be easier to catch `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` when your cat picker/component changes, and decrease the selection in the bullet picker/component if necessary, instead, to stop the bad selection happening in the first place.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thanks, so 'bullet' and 'cat' would have to be part of the same pickerView to make that work (i.e. one pickerView with two components)? Is that what you're suggesting? or should it be done with two completely separate picker views?

Comment: You could do it either way, either changing a component in the same picker view, or changing the (probably single) component in a separate one. As long as your delegate has references to each picker view, either way will work.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths ok, thanks, i've got it partially working (i.e. the method you suggested called after # of cats selected) but don't understand how to limit the number of `bullets` based on that selection. Can you take a glance at the update in the OP?

Comment: I don't think you need to limit the number of bullets, as in, change the number of rows in the other picker - you just need to change the selection. You can call `selectedRowInComponent:` on the other picker to find out what's currently selected. If bullets can be at most one less than cats, then you can compare the selected index of bullets to `row`. If that selected index is greater than or equal to `row`, then call `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` on the bullets picker view to set it to `row - 1`. You don't have to remove the higher values, just select a lower one.

Comment: In other words, suppose cats has 6 selected, and bullets has 4, which is fine. Then, cats changes to 3. You call `selectedRowInComponent:` on bullets and discover that it's greater than or equal to cats (since 4 >= 3). Having discovered this, you call `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` and set the selection for bullets to `row - 1`. You end up with cats showing 3, and bullets showing 2, which is what you want. If after cats changes, bullets is still no more than 1 less than cats, then you just leave it alone, since it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, here's an example view controller implementation to correct a bad selection before the unwind happens:

```
#import "CNBViewController.h"

@implementation CNBViewController {
    UIPickerView * _picker;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _picker = [UIPickerView new];
        _picker.delegate = self;
        _picker.dataSource = self;
        [_picker setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:_picker];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_picker attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:20]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_picker attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{

    //  Two components, cats and bullets

    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ( component == 0 ) {

        //  Let's have 10 rows for cats...

        return 10;
    }
    else {

        //  ...and 6 rows for bullets.

        return 6;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate methods

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //  Just populate with numbers from 2 up for cats (component 0) and
    //  1 up for bullets (component 1), otherwise we could end up with both
    //  being 1 which violates our constraint.

    int offset;
    if ( component == 0 ) {
        offset = 2;
    }
    else {
        offset = 1;
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row + offset];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ( component == 0 ) {

        //  Cats component changed, so get selected index of bullets component

        NSInteger bullets = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];

        //  If bullets is now greater than cats, reduce bullets

        if ( bullets > row ) {
            [pickerView selectRow:row inComponent:1 animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else if ( component == 1 ) {

        //  Bullets component changed, so get selected index of cats component

        NSInteger cats = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

        // If bullets is now greater than cats, reduce bullets

        if ( row > cats ) {
            [pickerView selectRow:cats inComponent:1 animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Notes:

- The header file for the view controller should declare the class as implementing the `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocols.
- For simplicity, there is no unwind going on, and I've just shown how to make the picker view behave.
- I've set the cats component to just show values from 2 upwards, and the bullets component to start from 1 upwards. If bullets must always be less than cats, and bullets starts at 1, it just makes no sense to have cats start any lower than 2, since it would never be a valid selection. When the selected row in each component is the same, therefore, our condition (that bullets must show no greater than cats less one) is satisfied, since if the selected row is 3 in both cases, then cats will display 5, and bullets will display 4. The condition is not satisfied if the selected row of the bullets component is greater than the selected row of the cats component.
- In `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`, if it's the cats component that changed, we just look at the value of the selected index in the bullets component, and if it exceeds that of cats, we set it to equal that of cats, to restore our constraint.
- If it's the bullets component that changed, we look at the value of the selected index in the cats component, and if it exceeds that of cats, again, we set it equal to that of cats, effectively undoing the change we've just been notified about.

Try playing around with it, changing either component to make the value of the right component greater than or equal to the left, and when you release the touch, you'll see it change to an acceptable value.